# Java - If Else Logic

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having a difficult time understanding why the second string does not print.  Even if I comment out the "third string" print line, there is no output.

```
public class SecretMessage {
       public static void main (String [] args) {
            int aValue=4;
            if (aValue > 0){
                if (aValue == 0)
                System.out.print("first string   ");
        }
        else 
        System.out.println("second string   ");
        System.out.println("third string   ");
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't the "second string" print?  I thought that anything under the else block would be executed, so both second and third string should be printed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to move it into the first `if` block

Comment: This is a nice example on why code formation and correct indentation matters and why one should always write `{` and `}` around `if`-, `else`-, `for`-,... bodies.

Comment: Use a proper editor that can format your code so that you can see what's going on.

Comment: [Here's](https://pastebin.com/Jpu48uv5) what it looks like with proper indentation, which makes it much clearer. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/yLPR74ac) what I would recommend you use instead (always using `{}`).

Comment: You set `aValue` to 4, then check if it's greater than 0.  4 is indeed greater than 0.  Why are you expecting the `else` block for that `if` condition to execute?  That is, why are you expecting `4 > 0` to be *false*?

Comment: @David OP's confusion comes from the fact that the third string is printed, while indentation gives the false impression that the second and third string belong to the same block and that either both of none of the two should be printed.

Comment: @Aaron: It looks like the OP is confused about what curly braces and/or if statements mean in general, and is just randomly littering the code with them.  Because even if that `else` wrapped both of the following statements there's still no reason that block would execute because 4 is still greater than 0.  The second comment above is probably the most useful take-away for the OP here... Paying attention to the format of one's code is important.  (Which is why I'm a fan of using Python for academic purposes... To instill into developers the idea that whitespace matters.)

Comment: @David Given the class name and the obvious disrespect to coding standards, I am guessing someone else provided OP with this code and asked him if he could guess why only the third statement was printed. I might be guessing wrong obviously, but I doubt telling him why the else block isn't entered is useful.

Comment: @Aaron, that is exactly what happened.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

If we indent your code properly and write the (implicit) braces, it becomes apparent what is going on:

```
public class SecretMessage {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int aValue = 4;
        if (aValue > 0){
            if (aValue == 0) {
                System.out.print("first string");
            }
        } else /* if (avalue <= 0) */ {
            System.out.println("second string");
        }
        System.out.println("third string");
    }
}
```

With `aValue = 4;`, the outer `if` is entered (`a > 0`), but not the inner `if` (`a == 0`). Thus, the `else` is not entered. Thus only `System.out.println("third string");` gets executed.

Some remarks on your code:

- The inner `if` can never be entered. If the outer `if` is entered, then `i` is `> 0` and can therefore not be `== 0`.
- You use `System.out.print(...)` and `System.out.println(...)`. I have a feeling that you want to use one or the other. For readability, you can also neglect the trailing blanks in those statements.
- the array-brackets (`[]`) should directly follow the type, without a space (`String [] args` -> `String[] args`).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition){
    //code
}else{
    //othercode
}
```

`if` block will be executed only if `condition` is `true`. `else` block will be executed only if `condition` is `false`.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm

Answer (score -1):

Because aValue is always more then 4 in your code that is `aValue=4;`.

Also you need to pay attention on the brackets.

```
public class SecretMessage {
       public static void main (String [] args) {
            int aValue=4;
            if (aValue > 0){
                if (aValue == 0)
                    System.out.print("first string   ");
            }
            else 
                System.out.println("second string   ");
            System.out.println("third string   ");
        }
    }
```

Is the same (but not as clean to read) as the code below, where it's more clear why only the second string is printed - explained [here](https://dzone.com/articles/omitting-braces-not-just-a-mat).

```
public class SecretMessage {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
        int aValue=4;
        if (aValue > 0){
            if (aValue == 0) {
                System.out.print("first string   ");
            }
        } else { 
            System.out.println("second string   ");
        }
        System.out.println("third string   ");
    }
}
```