# Returning integer value in String method still not getting any error

Tags: java

```
class Apple
{
    String tostring(int a , int b)
    {
        return ("Hello I'm "+a+" and I'm "+b);
    }

    public static void main(String arp[])
    {
        apple stupid_obj=new apple();
        String a=stupid_obj.tostring(4,5);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Have a look at this code.In `tostring` method I'm returning integer value instead of string and no error was thrown . I'm not getting that why java is accepting this code.

```
return ("Hello I'm "+a+" and I'm "+b);
```

Here `a` and `b` both are integer values still java is treating them as string.

How is this possible?

Comment: The `int` is getting converted to `String`

Comment: String and integer both are different things.How is this conversion taking place.

Comment: When you use `"string" + 1`, the result of that expression is a String.

Comment: Yeah got it.Thank You for your time.

Comment: Some remarks on your code: You should take care when you format code, because [code format matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879280/java-if-else-logic/). --- "*`String arp[]`*" - While possible, it is fronwed up on when you declare arrays c-style. Write the array brackets after the type instead of the name: `String[] arp` --- Most developers find it morereadable when one wirtes blanks around binary operators: `return ("Hello I'm "+a+" and I'm "+b);` -> `return ("Hello I'm " + a + " and I'm " + b);`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Next time I will keep this in mind.ThankYou for taking the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
String toString(int a , int b)
```

The signature of your method says: "I will return a string" (I fixed the casing for you, method names should go [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)).

Then

```
    return ("Hello I'm "+a+" and I'm "+b);
```

The `+` here isn't some integer addition or anything. It does a **string concatenation**. This means that the numeric values of `a` and `b` are simply turned into strings, and then a single string containing the various substrings is pulled together and returned.

This is very basic behavior, and absolutely "works as expected"!

Comment: Oh.Okay so java allow this.I should have researched more thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

this is normal operation in JAVA.
when One or more Integer value concatenate after a string value all integer value convert to String automatically...

> String a = "Hello" + 4+3+1;
>   so, a consist = "Hello431"..

other situation is ...
if many  Integer  integer value place before string it will execute normal operation and then concatenate with String value...

> String a = 4+3+1+"Hello"; so, a consist = "8Hello"..

Comment: Thanks for giving me more clarity on the topic.Others have already cleared my doubt.ThankYou for the time.